# Image feature is not fully clickable in openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a feature with an Image, it shows well on the map.

```
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        src: imagesource,
    })),
});
```

But when I add a select control on the layer

```
var selectcontrol = new ol.interaction.Select({
});
```

Only part of the image is clickable if the image is larger. Is there any settings to set here so that the whole image is clickable.

Here is a fiddle for the issue, you can see the cursor changes as you move to the center of the image, but the feature is not detected at the corners of the image

http://jsfiddle.net/c88keve7/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `renderBuffer` property when creating your vector layer. See [ol.layer.Vector](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html):

> **renderBuffer**: The buffer around the viewport extent used by the renderer when getting features from the vector source for the rendering or hit-detection. Recommended value: the size of the largest symbol, line width or label. Default is 100 pixels.

Comment: the link is dead